# ASP.NET 4.6 SPA, Publish entire wwwroot content dynamically via MsBuild

Tags: asp.net, webpack, msbuild

I have an ASP.NET 4.6 application which is hosting React.
All published content goes into wwwroot with an MsBuild step as below:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Call npm build -->
    <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'" Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="ClientApp">
    </Exec>
    <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'" Command="npm run build" WorkingDirectory="ClientApp">
    </Exec>
    <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'" Command="xcopy.exe  $(SourceDirectory) $(DestinationDirectory) /Y /E">
    </Exec>
  </Target>
```

The problem I have is when I publish via Azure DevOps.
Inside the project I have included this `ItemGroup`:

```
  </ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Views\_ViewStart.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Home\Index.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\Error.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />  
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I build, in Release mode, I can see the content available inside wwwroot, provided by Webpack but when the website is published, the folder wwwroot is there but empty. Of course I can't add the files to the solution because webpack produces dynamic content, so I have to use `<Content Include="wwwroot\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />`

Answer (score 1):

Found an old post. Actually because the files are generated at build time, the only way to include inside the output is to use this Pre-Deployment script:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Call npm build -->
    <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'" Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="ClientApp">
    </Exec>
    <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'" Command="npm run build" WorkingDirectory="ClientApp">
    </Exec>
    <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'" Command="xcopy.exe  $(SourceDirectory) $(DestinationDirectory) /Y /E">
    </Exec>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="SpaBeforeBuild" AfterTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="wwwroot\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

The order is:

1. Compile webpack and move from build folder into wwwroot
2. During publish, set all compiled files to "Content" which will allow MsBuild to put them into the PublishedWebsite folder